# How to make camera work like scanner in .Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created a webapplication. Basically it gets the barcode string from an uploaded Image. Now I am planning of making it more fancy. 
Instead uploading an image (either by iphone /ipad to capture the image or upload from library). I just want to scan the image from camera and get the barcode string to my backend database which will further load the pop up with invoice details.

Could someone share some ideas. I have researched all over the google and found that it can be done with own libraries. But I am not quite sure how to do that. Any tutorials or links that actually scans the barcode not just take a picture, upload and decode would be appreciated.

Comment: I would expect that any image analysis would need to be done with an app on the phone itself, so it would be a native iOS or Android app, which would need access to the photo library. So if you're trying to do it in .NET without first uploading the entire image, I don't think you'll find an answer.

Comment: Oh so you mean there cannot be a way to scan an image and send the barcode string to database without actually uploading an image. IF thats is what you are saying, I am totally lost. I never knew that it cannot be done.